# How do I compare current date with user input date?

Tags: swift, date, swiftui, calendar, compare

I'm really lost here after having Googled/tried what feels like everything. I am making a pantry management app, and trying to compare two dates (current date and expire date of a food item) to have the expire date in number of days. What i am currently doing is grabbing the hour and day as components from each and comparing them in a series of 'if-conditions.

```
let currentDate = Date()
let dateDif = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour], from: currentDate, to: fooditem.expireDate)
let Datedays = dateDif.day ?? 0
let Datehours = dateDif.hour ?? 0

if Datedays == 0 && Datehours == 0 {
Text("Expiring today") 
........
```

fooditem is an instance of the main entity with attributes such as 'weight', 'id', 'name' and 'expireDate'. It's created in a sheet where you fill out the necessary info about the individual food item. In the same sheet-view there's, among other things, the DatePicker described above and a button that saves the date by

```
Button(action: { guard self.foodName != "" else {return} 
let newOrder = FoodItem(context: viewContext) 
newOrder.expireDate = self.expireDate
```

which saves it to a `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) called viewContext`, which is managed by a `PersistenceController`. Then in my ContentView i access the food items `@FetchRequest(entity: FoodItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var fooditems: FetchedResults<FoodItem>` And put em in a list: `ForEach(fooditems) { fooditem in`. The code that crashes the application is then when I am trying to use the fooditem.expireDate within the ContentView for comparing the two dates.

The expireDate is of type Date() and determined through a DatePicker

```
DatePicker("Expire Date", selection: $expireDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
```

There is no problem building or in the canvas preview, but when running it, it quickly shows a blank white page and return to Xcode with the following error for the pasted code:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

This is found in the debug nav under thread 1

> #1 0x000000010084e854 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in
> ContentView.body.getter at
> /XX/Desktop/FoodApp/FoodApp/Views/ContentView.swift:87

And the above code is what's seems to be causing the problem at line 87. If a remove `'fooditem.expireDate'`, there's no problem, but it no longer gets the difference in dates.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated! (It's my first app and it's my first time reaching out for help, so if you need any additional info, please let me know)

Thanks and have a nice day,
Emil

Comment: What is `fooditem`?

Comment: Solid point, @JoakimDanielson. It's an instance based on my main entity with attributes such as 'weight', 'id', 'name' and 'expireDate'. It's created in a sheet where you fill out the necessary info about the individual food item.

Comment: "It's created in a sheet...", is the code where it crashes also in a sheet or is the object somehow transfered to this other object and if so how? It was more likely that `fooditem` is the issue here rather than the expiry date

Comment: Add this information to the question instead of posting it as comments so it will be easier to overview and read.